# Explanation of standard errors of predicted probabilities in mgcv ocat (ordinal logistic) family

Tags: standard-error, ordered-logit, mgcv

I am using `mgcv`'s `ocat` family to fit an ordinal logistic regression model. Ultimately I would like to obtain the fitted expected value of the outcome variable, i.e. 
$$\hat{\mu}(x) = \sum_{j=1}^R v_j \hat{p}_j(x)$$
for some value $x$ of the covariate vector, where $v_j$ is a numerical value assigned to each of the $R$ categories and $p_j(x) = \Pr(Y = j; x)$. This is straightforward enough, given that `predict(..., type = "response")` returns the fitted probabilities in each category.

But I would also like to get a standard error for $\hat{\mu}(x)$. `predict(, se = TRUE)` returns an additional vector of the standard errors of these probabilities, but I have two questions:

1. What is the derivation of their calculation? Looking under the hood of the predict function for `ocat` (via `ocat(R = 5)$predict`) reveals the code (NB this is a little confusing because it uses `R` differently to the documentation):

```
function (family, se = FALSE, eta = NULL, y = NULL, X = NULL, 
    beta = NULL, off = NULL, Vb = NULL) 
{
    ocat.prob <- function(theta, lp, se = NULL) {
        R <- length(theta)
        dp <- prob <- matrix(0, length(lp), R + 2)
        prob[, R + 2] <- 1
        for (i in 1:R) {
            x <- theta[i] - lp
            ind <- x > 0
            prob[ind, i + 1] <- 1/(1 + exp(-x[ind]))
            ex <- exp(x[!ind])
            prob[!ind, i + 1] <- ex/(1 + ex)
            dp[, i + 1] <- prob[, i + 1] * (prob[, i + 1] - 1)
        }
        prob <- t(diff(t(prob)))
        dp <- t(diff(t(dp)))
        if (!is.null(se)) 
            se <- as.numeric(se) * abs(dp)
        list(prob, se)
    }
    theta <- family$getTheta(TRUE)
    if (is.null(eta)) {
        discrete <- is.list(X)
        mu <- off + if (discrete) 
            Xbd(X$Xd, beta, k = X$kd, ks = X$ks, ts = X$ts, dt = X$dt, 
                v = X$v, qc = X$qc, drop = X$drop)
        else drop(X %*% beta)
        if (se) {
            se <- if (discrete) 
                sqrt(pmax(0, diagXVXd(X$Xd, Vb, k = X$kd, ks = X$ks, 
                  ts = X$ts, dt = X$dt, v = X$v, qc = X$qc, drop = X$drop, 
                  nthreads = 1)))
            else sqrt(pmax(0, rowSums((X %*% Vb) * X)))
        }
        else se <- NULL
        p <- ocat.prob(theta, mu, se)
        if (is.null(se)) 
            return(p)
        else {
            names(p) <- c("fit", "se.fit")
            return(p)
        }
    }
```

I can follow the calculation of the predicted probabilities $p$ from the cumulative probabilities $q$:

$$q_{i,j} = \begin{cases} 0 & j = 1 \\
\mathrm{logit}^{-1}(\theta_{j-1} - l_i) & j = 2, \cdots, R \\
1 & j = R+1
\end{cases}$$

$$p_{i,j} = p_{i,j+1} - p_{i,j} \qquad j = 1, \cdots, R$$

where $\theta_j$ are the thresholds and $l_i$ the linear predictors.

But I don't follow how the standard errors are calculated:

$$r_{i,j} = \begin{cases} 0 & j = 1 \\
-q_{i,j}(1 - q_{i,j}) & j = 2, \cdots, R \\
0 & j = R + 1 \end{cases}$$

$$s_{i,j} = \sigma_{i,j} \times | r_{i,j+1} - r_{i,j} |$$

where $\sigma_{i,j}$ is the `se` calculated below the `if (se) {` line about 3/4 of the way down the code above. I don't understand what that part is doing.

2. How could I ultimately calculate $\hat{\mathrm{SE}}(\hat{\mu}(x))$? I'd expect the fitted probabilities to be correlated, so I thought I would also need $\mathrm{Cov}(\hat{p}_j(x), \hat{p}_k(x))$, which isn't returned.